# PHP - PDO placeholder with table.column format

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I created a function *prepareValue()* which takes an array formatted like **$column => $value**, and replaces each **value** with **?** whilst preserving a copy of the original array for binding and executing later with PDO.

This works fine for queries like the following

```
$a = [
'company' => 'apple'
'item' => 'ipad'
];

prepareValue($a);

$sql = 'where company = ? and item = ?';
prepare($sql);
execute($a);
```

However, sometimes I am required to write queries where the array value is a *table.column* type value, which PDO doesnt seem to like being substituted with a placeholder.

```
$a = [
'companyId' => 'itemId';
]

prepareValue($a);

$sql = 'where companyId = ?';
prepare($sql);
execute($a);
```

This query does not work, but if I replace the **?** manually with **itemId** like the following

```
where companyId = itemId
```

The query works fine.

What is best in a scenario like this? Perhaps there is a way to prepare *table.column* type values?

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe you have to [read more about how prepared statements works](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). First your query is sent to the DBMS to compile and later the parameters. This way if you're comparing attributes they must follow together to be compiled.

Comment: @PauloASilva yes, but I am wondering if there is another way to run my query or some other type trick, For example, *WHERE NOT year = 2000* is equivilant to *WHERE year <> 2001*.
If a similar is possible for my circumstance, I can always structure my queries like so.

Comment: try to add `;` at the end of each code line and `,` between the `$a` values.

Comment: @BadToTheBone you can try with a query builder library